# Problem booting Windows volumes from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have 10 SSDs in my system, all with Windows/NTFS partitions - a few with MBRs on the disk, a few without (see [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/C3bc5zDJr4/)). I used to run Ubuntu through WSL and a hyper-v machine, but I decided I wanted to have a dual-booting Ubuntu-Windows system to have a full-fledged Ubuntu experience (e.g. being able to use my ultrawide screen with the 'right' driver).
I followed instructions to install Ubuntu from Windows, but always got stuck at the 'Updating' section. I tried out all 'solutions' I could find, but none of them worked. I then tried installing from a USB stick - same problem. Also trying boot-repair didn't work (see [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Rry7pnY2Fx/) for its report). When I looked in gparted I saw that many disks had red exclamation points in a red circle before them, but I couldn't find a way to fix that.
So I ended up, as a last resort, unplugging the power from all but one of my SSDs and installing Ubuntu onto that one from a bootable Ubuntu installation USB-stick. That worked perfectly. But I can now boot into Ubuntu, can 'see' all of my other drives but can no longer into any of my windows drives. Is there still a way to fix that? Ideally, I would like to get a grub that allows me to boot in all of my bootable partitions.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You didn't tell us what guide you are following, but it doesn't seem to be a good one.  I suggest that you use the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) - on step #6 there is a tooltip with a link to a guide that goes into dual boot configuration. If you want GRUB to recognize all operating systems then you need to install all operating systems the same way- in terms whether the OS is UEFI or not.  Windows is typically UEFI so you must install Ubuntu from a USB that was booted as UEFI.

Comment: Thanks! But so initially I used [this one](https://www.techspot.com/article/2422-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/). I did look at more of them, and all seem to concur that it was better to do this from Windows, as grub is a lot more flexible than WBM. And all of the times I got stuck, I tried things like  [this](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-ubuntu-20-04-installer-stuck-at-updates/), [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766978)  and other things I found.  As to your suggestion/link: right now ubuntu is installed & works  just fine. What I need is to boot into Windows.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? Will the content be the same? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: You can't install Ubuntu in dual boot configuration from Windows on the same machine while Windows is running. The source you linked is also wrong right from the beginning when it talks about MBR which hasn't been the default for Windows for about ten years.  Wouldn't it be better to follow a source that is canonical (little c and big C)?

Answer (score 1):

First, your [Boot Repair output](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/C3bc5zDJr4/) shows evidence of both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode Windows installations and of both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode GRUB (Linux boot loader) installations. With so many disks, it's hard to tell how either OS is booting. Importantly, GRUB is incapable of mixed-mode booting -- that is, if GRUB is installed in EFI mode, then it should be able to chainload to an EFI-mode Windows, and if GRUB is installed in BIOS mode, then it should be able to chainload to a BIOS-mode Windows; but an EFI-mode GRUB can't chainload to a BIOS-mode Windows, and a BIOS-mode GRUB can't chainload to an EFI-mode Windows. Thus, before beginning on an operation like yours, it's imperative that you know whether Windows is booting in BIOS mode or in EFI mode, and ensure that you install Ubuntu in the *same* mode. Today, I recommend sticking to EFI-mode booting on any but the oldest computers; but if your existing Windows installation is in BIOS mode, that might be the easier way to go. OTOH, it can be hard to control the boot mode if the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; the EFI's way of providing BIOS compatibility) is enabled. For more on this topic, see [my page on the CSM.](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

Second, if you're booting Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows, then running `sudo update-grub` should cause it to re-scan for OSes, thus detecting Windows and adding it to the GRUB configuration file. This command is unlikely to cause new problems even if Ubuntu and Windows are not booting in the same mode, although the complexity of your configuration might be a counter-indication. In principle, Boot Repair should be able to do something similar; but if you've booted Boot Repair in the wrong mode (in BIOS mode if Ubuntu and Windows are installed in EFI mode or vice-versa), then telling Boot Repair to fix the problem is unlikely to help and could even damage the working Ubuntu installation.

Third, if your Ubuntu and Windows installs are in different boot modes (EFI vs. BIOS), then your best bet is to harmonize them. How you do this depends on which OS is in which mode and which boot mode you want to do, so I can't present a simple solution; I'd need more information on your boot modes.

Comment: Thanks you for this! I will look more deeply into it this weekend. As for now, I have bought a new SSD, unplugged all other drives, installed both windows and ubuntu on the new one (in UEFI mode, as shown in my 'System information') as  and I now get a nice Grub Menu that allows me to boot into Ubuntu OR Windows 11. Which is what I wanted, so I'm happy about that! Hooking up all other drives made them all nicely available in both OSes. This weekend I will look into whether or not I can do sthg about  the other boot partition entries I see in Grub, but that do not boot through...